# JavaFX 8 JNLP Packaging: Classpath issue

Tags: java, maven, javafx-8, embedded-resource, jnlp

I'm trying to package my application as a Web Start usign the [ZenJava plugin for Maven](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/).

```
mvn -pl XXX com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:web -DskipTests -DmainClass=XXX.Main -Dproject.organization.name=XXX -DkeystoreAlias=selfsigned -DkeyStorePassword=XXX -DallPermissions=true -DkeyStore=./keystore.jks
```

This produces the following artifacts:

```
/lib
XXX-jfx.jar
XXX.html
XXX.jnlp
```

If I start my application from the jar, everything works as expected, but if I start the jnlp I get a [NPE regarding the Location like the one in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package).

What I'm using to read the required resource is

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("relative/path/from/package/root")
```

Tried all different ways to load it described in the linked topic without success. What am I missing? Doesn't the working jar mean my class loading is correct? Here's the important part of the JNLP as well.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="XXX-0.0.1.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Sample JavaFX Application</title>
    <vendor>XXX</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="8.0+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="xxx-jfx.jar" size="44875" download="eager" />
    <!-- Bunch of other jars here -->
  </resources>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="XXX-0.0.1" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="8.0+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="XXX.Main"  name="XXX-0.0.1" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path specific to your classpath?

Comment: Isn't this the same as the one I'm using (relative from package root)?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). BTW - I'm pretty sure it won't pick up the problem of having two identically targeted `resource` elements.  Fix that besides any other problems reported.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I run JaNeLa and there were only 2 red errors reported that likely were risen because JaNeLa requires Java 7 to run and I've analyzed Java 8 JNLP:

`cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jfx:javafx-runtime'. One of '{java, j2se, jar, nativelib, extension, property, package}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jfx:javafx-desc'. No child element is expected at this point.`

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've also merged the resources elements. Issue still persists. To make it clear, the resource I'm trying to get is located in application jar in a folder Y/Z and I'm referring to it as:

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("Y/Z/main.fxml")`

Comment: It will work under Java 8 just as well as Java 7 (Java is upwards compatible!).  The problem is that the DTD I used to develop the XSD that checks the JNLP does not account for Java-FX.  If you can find a DTD for a Java-FX based JNLP, I might update it.  `"Y/Z/main.fxml"` In what package it the class that calls that?  If it were `"/Y/Z/main.fxml"` it would not matter, but the way it is written, it does.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson It's in the same package

Comment: *"It's in the same package"*  Then the String should be either a relative URL `"./main.fxml"` or `"main.fxml"` or an absolute URL from the root of the class path `"/Y/Z/main.fxml"` (note **leading `/`**).  I'm surprised you have not tried it yet!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson The thing is, I did try them out, I even setup a testing code just now for the sake of the argument, here's the result:
`main.fxml did not work!
./main.fxml did not work!
X/Y/main.fxml did not work!
/X/Y/main.fxml did not work!`
PS. I'm using Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource() method.

Comment: I've updated to JDK 1.8.45 and now I'm hitting something that looks like [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051030?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel). Screw it, I'll do without jnlp.