# javaFX, throws NullPointerException, Location is required

Tags: java, javafx, fxmlloader

i have seen other answers but nothing have helped me

(sorry new to GUI only know basics of swing)

this is main class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Main.fxml"));

  Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } 

    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

this is another class whose method i want to invoke

```
package application;


import java.util.Random;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;


public class MainController {

@FXML
private Label myMessage;
void generaterandom (ActionEvent event){
    Random rand=new Random();
    int myrand=rand.nextInt(50)+1;
    myMessage.setText(Integer.toString(myrand));
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(myrand));


}

}
```

i will add xml file if needed .

[image]

this is the error i am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl    .java:863)
    at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:32    6)
    at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at     com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Comment: What if I told you that  `getClassLoader` doesn't read from the package where your source code is located?

Comment: i was having same error before after searching stack overflow i reached  a sloution to add getclassloader() 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package

Comment: same code was working fine few hours ago !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)` will load a resource from a path relative to the classpath. Since you placed the FXML file in the `application` pacakge, you need:

```
Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application/Main.fxml"));
```

If you just use `getClass().getResource(...)`, and do not prefix the path with `/`, it will load from a path relative to the current class. So

```
Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
```

should also work.

Make sure that your FXML file is being exported to the build folder, along with the `.class` files.

Comment: yes it is being exported
and both of these solutions are giving same error . is it possible some thing is wrong with my machine ?

Comment: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/Javafx%20tesr/bin/application/Main.fxml:7

Comment: That isn't the "same error" though. Why did you say you were getting the "same error"? Since the previous error message was reporting that it couldn't find the fxml file, and the new error message is saying it has found an error on line 7 of the fxml file, I think you can safely assume this fixed the original error, no?

Comment: not same as previous but new same error .. 
i was going to write both thing in one comment but got splitted due to mistake .. 

so new error is in xml file now ?

Comment: That's what the error message says, yes. At line 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{    
scene.getStylesheets().add(new File(pathTocssFile).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: i am not using css file in it . .(sorry new to GUI only know basics of swing)

Comment: instead of FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Main.fxml")); try FXMLLoader.load(new File(pathToFXMLFile).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());

Comment: "new File" write it as it is ? 
because it is asking to import java.io 
wich creates another error

and path to xml file "srx/application/main.fxml"?