# i want to change the scene javafx scene builder

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

i using javafx and scene builder2.0. 
i want to change the scene from mainmenu.fxml to koreanfood.fxml
i ran program. scene is appeared.
i clicked on. error occured.

main.java:

```
 package application;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class Main extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            try {
                Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainmenu.fxml"));
                primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));         
                primaryStage.setTitle("recipe");
                primaryStage.show();
    //          primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

mainmenu.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <GridPane hgap="30.0" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="200.0" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="682.0" vgap="30.0">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <AnchorPane onMouseClicked="#clickmainmenu" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="101.0" fitWidth="103.0" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="7.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../2학년%202학기/오픈소스프로젝트/project/iconfinder_Food_C226_2427886.png" />
                     </image></ImageView>
                  <Label layoutX="54.0" layoutY="119.0" text="한식">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="21.0" />
                     </font></Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <children>
                  <Button layoutY="1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#clickmainmenu" prefHeight="123.0" prefWidth="119.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="86.0" fitWidth="85.0" layoutX="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../../2학년%202학기/오픈소스프로젝트/project/dim-sum.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label layoutX="37.0" layoutY="89.0" text="중식">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="86.0" fitWidth="75.0" layoutX="21.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <Label layoutX="300.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="94.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="뭐먹어">
         <font>
            <Font size="72.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private void clickmainmenu(ActionEvent event) {

            try {
                Parent koreanfood = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("koreanfood.fxml"));

                Scene scene = new Scene(koreanfood);

                Stage primaryStage = (Stage)koreanfood.getScene().getWindow();

                primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i want to change the scene from mainmenu.fxml to koreanfood.fxml
but error occurred.

i tried to replace ActionEvent with MouseEvent
error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Controller.clickmainmenu(Controller.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

koreanfood.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="327.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="99.0" prefWidth="146.0" text="한식">
         <font>
            <Font size="70.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <GridPane hgap="20.0" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="121.0" prefHeight="448.0" prefWidth="678.0" vgap="20.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="99.0" fitWidth="121.0" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                  <Label layoutX="54.0" layoutY="104.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="58.0" text="111" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: You want to change the name ? or change all the file ?

Comment: i want to load different fxml file "koreanfood.fxml"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package)

Comment: @Yuheon Can you provide the koreanfood.fxml file ?  Because it seems there are differences between the components of your koreanfood.fxml file and the Controller file that you want to use with it

Comment: I succeed in changing the path. but new error occurred.  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.Controller.clickmainmenu(Controller.java:20)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     and so on...

Comment: I guess I have error in this sentence "Stage primaryStage = (Stage)koreanfood.getScene().getWindow();"(in Controller.java)

Comment: Oh , I succeed by changing from "Stage primaryStage = (Stage)koreanfood.getScene().getWindow();" to "Stage primaryStage = (Stage)((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();" But  I don't know what this mean. Thank Calips and Gnas. I would not have been able to do without your help.

Comment: Please use the search feature; this question has been asked and answered dozens of times already.

Answer (score 0):

for loading Windows or stages i've created this mehod by myself

```
  public static Object loadWindow(URL loc, String title, Stage parentStage, String test) {
    Object controller = null;
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(loc);
        Parent parent = loader.load();
        controller = loader.getController();
        Stage stage = null;
        if (parentStage != null) {
            stage = parentStage;
        } else {
            stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        }
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(parent));
        stage.show();
        setStageIcon(stage);
        if ("yes".equals(test)) {
            stage.setMaximized(true);
        } else {
            stage.setMaximized(false);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return controller;
}
```

and the call method it's like this

```
loadWindow(getClass().getResource("/package/YOURSTAGE.fxml"), "TITLE", null,"no");
```

Comment: Thanks Samer. I'll try this method!