# Multple Errors While running javafx executable jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I have build a javafx application with which runs perfectly when run from Intellij idea platform. i have then created a executable jar file with manifest file as shown below.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: Amber mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin jfoenix-8.0.8
JavaFX-Version: 8.0
Main-Class: CRM.Crm
```

When i run the jar file from commandline as..

```
C:\Users\DELL\IdeaProjects\Amber\out\artifacts\Amber>java -jar Amber.jar
```

The Error Shown is as below..

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:




 file:/C:/Users/DELL/IdeaProjects/Amber/out/artifacts/Amber/Amber.jar!/
CRM/Crm.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at CRM.Crm.start(Crm.java:20)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at CRM.Crmcontroller.LoadUI(Crmcontroller.java:91)
    at CRM.Crmcontroller.initialize(Crmcontroller.java:69)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application CRM.Crm
```

Please Tell me why this Error is happening.

Comment: The error means some `getResource(...)` call inside `CRM.Crmcontroller#LoadUI` is returning `null`. In other words, the resource isn't being found. Without a [mre] demonstrating the problem, however, it'll be difficult to provide any actual help.

Comment: Please see the issue that is described very similarly: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000480664-My-application-is-not-running-through-jar and the solution suggested for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507591/javafx-location-is-required-even-though-it-is-in-the-same-package

Answer (score 0):

```
at CRM.Crmcontroller.LoadUI(Crmcontroller.java:91)
```

the location used at line 91 is not found or not set

try checking the path

Comment: but the same code is running perfectly from Intellij.

Comment: I faced a similar problem, I could run the code from the eclipse perfectly but in the jar file nothing works, Just re-check that line one more time maybe it is not the problem but you have to know why the JVM tells that the exception was fired there